# Does Spark write intermediate shuffle outputs to disk

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm reading [Learning Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do), and I don't understand what it means that Spark's shuffle outputs are written to disk. See Chapter 8, Tuning and Debugging Spark, pages 148-149:

> Spark’s internal scheduler may truncate the lineage of the RDD graph
>   if an existing RDD has already been persisted in cluster memory or on
>   disk. A second case in which **this truncation can happen is when an RDD
>   is already materialized as a side effect of an earlier shuffle**, even
>   if it was not explicitly persisted. This is an under-the-hood
>   optimization that takes advantage of the fact that **Spark shuffle
>   outputs are written to disk**, and exploits the fact that many times
>   portions of the RDD graph are recomputed.

As I understand there are different persistence policies, for example, the default `MEMORY_ONLY` which means the intermediate result will never be persisted to the disk.

When and why will a shuffle persist something on disk? How can that be reused by further computations?

Comment: https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When

It happens with when operation that requires shuffle is *first time* evaluated (action) and cannot be disabled

### Why

This is an optimization. Shuffling is one of the expensive things that happen in Spark.

### How that can be reused by further computations?

It is automatically reused with any subsequent action executed on the same RDD.

Comment: Does Spark persists shuffle output each time or it may skip writing shuffle results to disk?

Comment: It reuses shuffle files so it should happen once.

Comment: Sorry, I mean if it's possible that Spark won't write shuffle outputs to the disk?

Comment: I'll happens for each shuffle phase. It is mandatory part of the mechanism. and it cannot be skipped or disabled.